# Upload por FTP com PHP, não está enviando a imagem

Tags: php, ftp

Com base no código abaixo estou tentando enviar uma imagem através do protocolo FTP, mas o arquivo não está sendo enviado, algo me diz que é no caminho do arquivo, eu informe a caminho absoluto.

```php
<?php

$arquivo = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$servidor = 'servidor';
$target_dir = "destino";
$con_id = ftp_connect($servidor) or die( 'Não conectou em: '.$servidor );
ftp_login( $con_id, 'usuario', 'senha' );

    if ($arquivo != "" && $_FILES != NULL){
            $uploadOk = 1;
        //echo $image_name;die;
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";die;
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";die;
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";die;
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";die;
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            ftp_put( $con_id, $target_dir.$arquivo['name'], $arquivo['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual o erro que você está recebendo? Se não está recebendo vale a pena seguir o [template básico](http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php) que captura erros de login, transporte, etc. **PS:**, faltou o `ftp_close($con_id);`

Comment: é estranho pq eu fiz o código todo e ele não retorna nada, bom, esse ftp é minha própria documentação do meu site, isso causa algo? Assim, estou fazendo um upload no ftp da minha própria aplicação na qual eu executo esse processo. Tentei fazer da maneira padrão do php mas também não deu.

Comment: O problema do seu código é que ele não está obtendo o resultado das funções `ftp_login`, `ftp_put`, etc. O código pode falhar silenciosamente em vários pontos. Nós também não temos os parâmetros (arquivo, parâmetros de conexão ftp, etc) para simular uma execução. É importante que você encontre qual comando está falhando. Já tentou dar um echo em cada um dos parâmetros, bem como em `con_id` e nos retornos de `ftp_login` e `ftp_put`? Se algum deles for `FALSE` você já sabe o que aconteceu. Se não vai saber onde o código falhou.

Comment: eu usei um try{} e ele passo reto vou dar um echo para ver

Comment: bom, o con_id retorna Resource id #xx (x=numeros) ftp_login retorna 1 (que eu acho q é verdadeiro) e ftp_put vazio.

Comment: Vazio? Essa função deve retornar um `bool` ([documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php)). Coloca um `echo` antes e depois do `ftp_put` para ter certeza que entrou nele.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24767/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-leo-soares-fontoura).

Comment: Descobri o erro, a rota do meu arquivo estava retornando totalmente errada, não sei o porque, então resolvi e o update funcionou.